# One server for different clients

Tags: java, c#, web-services, rmi

I am writing to ask how it would be possible to make one server for different clients. Let's say I have client in RMI in JAVA and I have client in C# it should both use the same server. How it would be possible to be made? That if I am making concurrent changes the system won't crash or respond crappy results.

Thank you for your advise.

**EDIT* Java uses RMI C# uses web services**
Also, I am using the database which stores the sent data. So how the database could identify which result put first if the request was sent at the same time?

Comment: You should use a protocol that is supported by all platforms. For instance, wcf, http. The connection/transport of data should be independend from the platform.

Comment: first line in Oracle's RMI tutorial - "The Java Remote Method Invocation (RMI) system allows an object running in one Java virtual machine to invoke methods on an object running in another Java virtual machine. RMI provides for remote communication between programs written in the Java programming language."

Comment: @aiguy It would still be possible to create a server that supports RMI and other connection methods. It would just be unnecessary extra work.

Comment: Yes but I have multiple clients running on different platforms but I want to have one server which would be able to handle requests from different platforms.

Comment: @Kayaman maybe. But I think we can agree there is no good reason to. If you can think of a way to implement it, though, I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: You should take a transport/call method that is easily supported on the target platforms you need to without the need of implementing it yourself.

Comment: @aiguy I can think of plenty of ways to implement it, but I'd never do it myself. Extra complexity for no added value.

Comment: @Sr1dEo Why don't they both use webservices?

Comment: It is task requirement. To use RMI and Web ervices that would be able to connect to one server and to handle requests. Is it possible to write that kind of server in JAVA?

Comment: Because now I am using RMI server to handle java requests and tomcat to handle web services requests but it's two different servers. Which are not notyfing each other about made change and when u make changes for example at the same time it crashes or populates some unrelated data.

Comment: Simple and clean solution, ditch the RMI client and write a webservice client for Java.

Comment: I cannot get rid of RMI it is a task requirement.

Comment: Well, then this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Requirements: You have to make a 3-tier architecture.
You have to use RMI and Web Services.
The system should in general be implemented in Java with at least one part
implemented in C#.

Comment: This is not sufficiently detailed to be implementable as is. Use RMI for what exactly?